# Find values in a matrix and put them into a vector

Tags: matlab, vectorization

It must be simple, but surprisingly I couldn't find an answer to this problem here or by trial-and-error.
I want to get values out of a matrix (according to some condition) and place the values into a vector.  I also need the subscript indices of the matching values.  There is a lot of data so for loops are out.

This is a correct (but iterative) answer:

```
[I,J] = find(A > 5);
values = zeros(numel(I),1);
for i=1:numel(I)
    values(i) = A(I(i),J(i));
end
```

I tried `values = A(I,J)` but this is n-by-n instead of n-by-1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can implicitly treat the matrix like a vector ([linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html#f1-85511)):

```
I = find(A > 5);
values = A(I);
```

Note that you can do this more efficiently with [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html#bq7egb6-1):

```
values = A(A > 5);
```

Comment: I wonder if it's faster to use sub2ind and find or find (for the indices) and logical indexing...